# SQL query for fetching clicked/purchased items in the past n days and also getting the past activities

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to figure out how to write an SQL query to build the dataset described as follows:

Extract items that were clicked in the past 49 days to construct the target items and the corresponding click behaviors that happened before the target items were clicked. Using one target item **a** as an example, we set the day that **a** is clicked as the last day and the behaviors that this user took in the past 14 days.

Here's a sample of the table that I'm querying from:

- user_id
- item_id
- action (click, purchased)
- timestamp

| user id | item id | action | time_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | click | 2022-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 3 | click | 2022-03-02 00:10:00 |
| 1 | 4 | click | 2022-03-02 00:12:00 |
| 2 | 9 | click | 2022-03-02 00:01:00 |
| 2 | 11 | click | 2022-03-02 00:08:00 |
| 2 | 3 | click | 2022-03-02 00:12:00 |
| 2 | 2 | click | 2022-03-02 00:14:00 |
| 2 | 4 | click | 2022-03-02 00:18:00 |

The result should look something like this:

| user id | item id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |

where the last item id for each user is the target item and the remaining user_id/item_id pairs are ordered w.r.t time_stamp.

Thanks

Comment: You should definitely give us some sample data to understand how the data needs to be transformed

Comment: Thanks @AleixCC for the feedback. I've added a sample data